# Excel file showing aspx page after download from web folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the following code to download an excel file from my asp.net/vb.net website:

```
Dim msFilePath As String
Dim msFileName As String
msFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Template.xls")
msFileName = msFilePath
Dim mAttachFileName As String = "Template.xls"
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & mAttachFileName & """")
Response.Flush()
```

The excel file is a template being provided with column headings and that is all it contains. When I click on the download button in my website it prompts me to save/open the file with the correct name 'Template.xls'. Once I open it is displaying the aspx page inside the excel file instead of the data that is supposed to be in the file and giving me an error saying it is missing the css file. I have debugged through and the path is pointing to the correct location of the file so I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem, I'd like to tell why yours doesn't work but i'm not that smart. Instead i'll just tell you what code i've used that now works for me:

replace

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & mAttachFileName & """")
Response.Flush()
```

with

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & mAttachFileName & """")
Response.TransmitFile(FilePath)
Response.End()
```

I know that response.End() is deprecated but without it I always get all that html garbage...

Comment: not sure why its happening either but your code worked n thats what matters!! been stuck at it for days...thanks very much for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly started having the problem in my machine. I tried the application in other machines (web app) and it worked. I had to rule out coding issues at that point. I tried a million things and nothing worked. I rebooted the machine and voila...it worked. 
Rebooting is always my last option, believe me.

Comment: Switch it on and off again? =)